# AS3 MOUSE_DOWN Sprite not working

Tags: actionscript-3

For the life of me I can't remember how to make a sprite respond to MOUSE_DOWN and MOUSE_UP...works if I link the listener to the stage but not a sprite...What am I doing wrong?

```
private function allClassesReady(e:Event):void
{
    userName00 = e.currentTarget.userName0;
    chatArea00 = e.currentTarget.ui0.chatArea0;
    chatInput00 = e.currentTarget.ui0.chatInput0;

    btnArr00 = e.currentTarget.ui0.btnArr0;
    userList00 = e.currentTarget.ui0.userList0;
    msgSo00 = e.currentTarget.shaob0.msgSo0;

    userListSo00 = e.currentTarget.shaob0.userListSo0;

    main00.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, displayKey);
    main00.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, scrollsTxtArea, false, 0, true);
    /*listens for the enter key on the keyboard so we can send message when pressed*/

    btnArr00[0].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, sendMsg, false, 0, true);
    btnArr00[0].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, sendBtnRelease, false, 0, true);
}
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the Sprite you're concerned about is having the event listeners added correctly? Are you sure that `btnArr00[0]` is the Sprite.

Comment: oops btnArr00[1] was on top *sheepish grin*

Comment: You can try : (btnArr00[0] as Sprite).addEventListener(.....);

Comment: For complex objects, I sometimes fill a transparent hit area as the top layer, then disable `mouseEnabled` / `mouseChildren`.